# Do I need to pay for my family, who are 'additional applicants' when applying for Australian work visa?

Tags: working-visas, australia, family, payment

I am from family of 4 (two adults, two children (5 and 7)). I was looking into Australian work visas and was wondering how many persons to I need to pay for when applying for (190) visa... I would be the only person who works from my family...

In visa fee [calculator here](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/190-#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ProductQuestionsPanel_VisaDetailsPageTrimmingControl3) (screenshot below) one can select applicants over and under 18, which seem to imply that if I want to bring my family over to Australia I will have to pay ~1,800.00 AUD for adult and ~900.00 AUD for child.

[image]

**Who are 'additional applicants' when applying for Australian work visa?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it correctly. After a bit of searching I found the [Examples visa pricing charges](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Fees/explanation-of-visa-application-charges/examples-visa-pricing-charges) page.

There are two examples and both detail that partners/spouses and children are considered additional applicants. It also points out that there's a surcharge if you pay by credit card (currently 0.98% VISA/Mastercard, 1.5% American Express, and 2.0% Diners Club International).

Here's an excerpt from the main applicant with spouse and children example.

> 1. Paul applies for an Independent ELICOS Sector (subclass 570) visa in
>      his home country, by lodging a paper application.
> 2. When he applies,
>      he includes his 30-year old wife and 2-year old child as additional
>      visa applicants.
> 3. Paul must pay the base application charge for this
>      visa as the main applicant, the additional applicant charge for his
>      wife (additional applicant 18 years or over) and the additional
>      applicant charge for his child (additional applicant under 18 years
>      old) as additional applicants.